# How do I write the Regex for a Node app that acts like a simple JS linter with a condition as well

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Been tasked to write a Nodejs app that searches through files and reads every one line by line, if the query is found in any file then return the filename, the query found and the line number. I'm almost nearing completion however the last two bits have me confused ,one being the regex for the following:

Style guide
o “let a=1” - no space and no semi colon
o “const b =2;” - no space

So basically I need the regex to match this pattern
I also have to report on which rule has been broken

My current app returns the following:
The file name, the condition and the line number it occurred on already just missing the regex and the statement of which rule is broken
{ filePath: 'test.js', matches: Map(1) { 'let a = 1' => [ 1 ] } }

The code for the entire Nodejs app is:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");

const SearchFiles = (readStream, filePath, queries) => {
  let lineCount = 0;
  let matches = new Map();
  queries.forEach((query) => matches.set(query, []));

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readStream.on("line", (line) => {
      lineCount++;
      for (let query of matches.keys()) {
        if (searchForTerm(line, query))
          matches.set(query, [...matches.get(query), lineCount]);
      }
    });

    readStream.on("close", () =>
      resolve({
        filePath,
        matches,
      })
    );
  });
};
const searchForTerm = (line, query) => line.match(query);

const createLineInterfaces = (filePaths) =>
  filePaths.map((filePath) => {
    const readStream = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
    });
    return {
      filePath,
      readStream,
    };
  });

const filesToSearch = ["test.js", "test2.js"];
const queriesToSearch = ["let a = 1"];
let searchProms = createLineInterfaces(
  filesToSearch
).map(({ readStream, filePath }) =>
  SearchFiles(readStream, filePath, queriesToSearch)
);

Promise.all(searchProms).then((searchResults) =>
  searchResults.forEach((result) => console.log(result))
);
```

The contents of the files are:
test.js => let a = 1 // On line 1
test2.js => let b = 8; //On line 3

Running the app on the two above returns:

```
{ filePath: 'test.js', matches: Map(1) { 'let a = 1' => [ 1 ] } }
{ filePath: 'test2.js', matches: Map(1) { 'let a = 1' => [] } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, if you want a regex to match an equals sign with an adjacent non-space character, or a line without a semicolon at the end:

```js
\S=|=\S|[^;]$
```

E.g.

```js
const rx = /\S=|=\S|[^;]$/;
rx.test("const b =2;");    // true
rx.test("const b = 2");    // true
rx.test("const b = 2;");   // false
```

Comment: Thanks alot man! solved the rest after having this